# OJB ReportQuery join question

Tags: sql, join, criteria, ojb

Given three tables:

```
People: {Person_Id, Age}

Accounts: {Account_Id, Person_Id, Account_Type}

Age_Ranges: {Age_Range_Id, Age_Range_Label, Lower_Bound, Upper_Bound}
```

I'm trying to represent the following SQL query using OJB (without resorting to a QueryBySQL):

```
select ar.Age_Range_Label, count(a.Account_Id)
from People p
inner join Accounts a on p.Person_Id = a.Person_Id
inner join Age_Ranges ar on p.Age between ar.Lower_bound and ar.Upper_Bound
where a.Account_Type = 'Chequing'
```

The java code I have so far looks like this:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.addEqualTo("Account_Type", "Chequing");

// join on Age_Ranges based on the person's Age
criteria.???

ReportQueryByCriteria q = QueryFactory.newReportQuery(Accounts.class, criteria);
q.setAttributes(new String[] {"Age_Range_Label", "count(Account_Id)"});
q.addGroupBy("Age_Range_Label");   
...
```

But I'm unsure how to join up with the Age_Ranges table such that I can group on the Age_Range_Label column.

Any insight?